# If image url not exist on server replace url with other (multiple time)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made lastposter avatar for my forum system.
What i want : when user avatar img not exist change file type multiple time. Such example; if `user_{userid}_avatar.png` not exist change url to `user_{user_id}_avatar.jpg` and again it's not exist change to `user_{userid}_avatar.gif` and etc.({user_id} coming as php variable that's no matter).

```html
<div class="lpavatar"><img src="/avatar/user_{user_id}.png"/></div>
<div class="lpavatar"><img src="/avatar/user_{user_id}.png"/></div>
<div class="lpavatar"><img src="/avatar/user_{user_id}.png"/></div>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

Javascript:

```
var img_types = ['jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];
var avatar = '';
for(var i=0;i<img_types.length();i++) {
    avatar = new File("/path/to/avtar." + img_types[i]);

    // See if the file exists
    if(avatar.exists()){
        break;
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    // put allowed image types in this array
    $img_types = ['jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];
    // avatar URL will be stored in here
    $avatar = '';
    // loop over the image_types array
    foreach($img_types as $img_type) {
        $avatar = '/path/to/user_{userid}_avatar.' . $img_type;
        // check if the files exists
        if(file_exists($avatar)) {
            // exit the foreach loop, because we found the image
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I do it with plan Javascript.

Comment: One last thing; some avatar can have different file type same type, like this;
`<div class="lpavatar"><img src="/avatar/user_{user_id}.png"/></div>
<div class="lpavatar"><img src="/avatar/user_{user_id}.jpg"/></div>
<div class="lpavatar"><img src="/avatar/user_{user_id}.gif"/></div>` how can handle this?

Comment: @novruzrhmv You mean that a user can have multiple images? Like a jpeg and a gif? And you want both these URLs?

Comment: No, i mean different users can different file type and showing like this; user_1.jpg, user_2.png, user_3.gif

Comment: @novruzrhmv That should be working with this code already isn't it?

Comment: given code not working, i think you use `.src` instead of file function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this.

```
function image_exists(image_url){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status != 404;

}
```

Comment: I can't adapt to this my code, can you edit answer?